# Override wordpress login redirect function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a login function stored in a custom plugin that over-rides the standard Wordpress login to, once a user logs in, redirect them to a desired page:

```
function admin_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
global $user;
if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
if( in_array( "administrator", $user->roles ) ) {
return $redirect_to;
} else {
return home_url();
}
}
else
{
return $redirect_to;
}
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "admin_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

This works a treat but I now need to build an additional/alternative login page that, if used, redirects the user to a different landing page.

It seems that my only three logical options are to either:

- Write code in the new login page to ignore the plugin redirect function (is this even possible!?)
- Recognize the login template/form the user is using and build this logic into the above function or
- Over ride the redirect function (above) within the new/alternative login page.

Does anyone know if either of these are possible and if so how would i action it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to create a new login page and define the redirect after login action on that page.

The page template for the custom login page will look something like this:

```
<?php
    // Define custom redirect
    $custom_redirect = "REDIRECT_URL";

    // If user is logged out
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args = array(
            'redirect' => $custom_redirect
        );

        // Output the login form with arguments
        wp_login_form( $args );
    } 
    // Display below if user is logged in
    else {
        wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
        echo " | ";
        wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
    }
?>
```

You can either wrap this inside a `custom_login_form()` function inside functions.php and then call that function inside your custom login page template or place it directly in the custom login page template. You can name the custom page template `page-login.php`, which will automatically apply to a WP page named "login".

[Full guide on creating a custom page template for the login page](https://themetrust.com/build-custom-wordpress-login-page/).

[Full guide on customizing the login form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page).